# as, when, and while in "when you are having a bath"

Tags: conjunctions

I saw the following sentences and am wondering whether **as**, **when** and **while** are interchangeable.

> As / While / When I was walking down the street I saw Joe driving a
>   Porsche.
>
> The telephone always rings as / while / when you are having a bath.
>
> As / While /When they were playing cards, somebody broke into the
>   house.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**as** and **while** don't partner with things that take place in a split second:

> She was singing as|while he shattered the glass window with a small
>   brass hammer in a single stroke.

(example of what not to say)

But **when** does.  **when** is the most versatile of the three.

Comment: Your generalization and example don't seem to match; shouldn't "as" or "while" be replaced by "when" in the example?

Comment: Can "as" be used in "People should use some sunscreen while / when they are outdoors for a long time"?

Comment: It was meant to be an example of misuse.

Comment: **are outdoors** is not a duration but a state.  **as** partners with ongoing events, actions-in-progress.

Answer (score 0):

*When X, Y* - X is a single point in time.  It's possible and likely that Y interrupted X.

*As X, Y* - X is a single point in time.  It's not likely that Y interrupted X - Y and X happened concurrently.

*While X, Y* - X is a duration of time, not a single point in time.  Y may or may not have interrupted X.

If X requires a lot of time or is a long, continuous activity, *while* should be used over *when*.

If Y is not something that requires physical/mental interruption of X, the difference between these doesn't matter very much, but can imply the degree of importance or attention Y has.

> When I was walking down the street I saw Joe driving a Porsche (Maybe I stopped walking when I saw him.)
>
> While I was walking down the street I saw Joe driving a Porsche (The walk was a long walk, and maybe it was significant that I saw him driving a Porsche but I might not have stopped in my tracks at that moment.)
>
> As I was walking down the street I saw Joe driving a Porsche (Joe might have been far away and I didn't bother to stop walking.)